# "Repair" Android SDK Manager in VS 2019 failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to write an app in **Xamarin** for my company. **The SDK manager** keeps failing to install everything, seen in this [screencap of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGTWv.png).

> "Operation failed: Downloading Android Emulator - "The decryption
>   operation failed, see inner exception.""

Has anyone else had this problem and worked it out? Or at the least how can I look up this inner exception for more info? Any help is appreciated, I've been stuck on this for days. I'm still very new to programming so please explain things to me like I'm 9, thanks.

Edit: I can't really provide more details because I haven't done anything so far. I try to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) but when I open the SDK manager, it asks me to Repair, which fails with the messages in the screencap. My project is still basically blank at this point. What few forum posts I can find that are at all relevant refer to a different problem that happens to have the same error message.
I've tried starting over on another computer. No dice.

Comment: You need to provide more details and also what you've done so far.

Comment: You mentioned in your edit that you tried a fresh install on another computer. Is the user on the machine you're using an Administrator? I know I ran into some trouble with that on an older version of Visual Studio for Mac, but it was unrelated to your issue and I imagine they would have fixed that by now.

Comment: Yes, he is the admin. These are quite robust desktops in a drafting office, with only 1 user per. He also had Windows Pro which I thought might help, but didn't.

Comment: @Drafter5050 Hi , first you need to check the network of computer , be sure that it can connect to sdks source. Second have a try with this steps( Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings) to see the settings of android . And you can check that Sdk file location , then share the screenshot of folder .We can see whether sdk is insatalled correctly .

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can remove the need for that SDK that cannot be installed by going to the AndroidManifest.xml file and changing the Target Android version to just 26. Then, open your Android project options and change the "compile using android version(target framework)" to 26. And then repairing it shouldnt require installing SDK 28

Comment: Having the same problem, when VS2019 tries to download `Android Emulator v28.0.25 Started` by `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5395263.zip`. Works well in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions still didn't help, but I managed to configure and connect my phone and am using it as a test platform rather than the emulator. Takes longer, but at least it works.